# How to deploy a Next.js App on AWS using nginx

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

I'm currently following a tutorial on youtube on how to deploy a react app on AWS. He's using gitbash and nginx to do it. The problem is that currently I'm using a prebuilt template from themefor*st and the app they made includes next.js in it. Using this template, when I try to do "
npm run build" it does not provide me with an index.html file inside the build folder which is what the Youtube video tutorial points to, to run the front end on the AWS. I'm new to hosting a website but I think the problem lies in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default configuration for the location. I look up answers on the internet but couldn't find anything helpful, closest so far are this documentation which I do not understand

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

I need help and if there are any questions regarding the file, I will try my best to explain them! Thank you

Here's the link to the youtube video I referred to above
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE8mJ1OYjmM